# Why do wire and reg need interval notation instead of size in verilog?

Tags: syntax, verilog

A basic arg looks like this: input wire [3:0] in1

Why do we need to set an interval `[3:0] in1` instead of something like `4'in1`?

I had no luck with finding an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Short answer: because Verilog standard says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the honest answer is that it's just because of [Verilog specification](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). Range notation however enables you to do some interesting hacks, such as picking only limited  ranges: 
`[3:1]`or reversing the order of selection `[1:3]`.